# How to converts the string to alternate upper and lower case in php (Laravel Zero)?

Tags: php, laravel, string, input, command-line-interface

i am working on Laravel Zero and created new command that will display the user input to show in uppercase and lowercase.

is there a way to also display the output alternate upper and lower case?

here is the command:

```
class UppercaseCommand extends Command
{
/**
 * The signature of the command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'converts';

/**
 * The description of the command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Converts the string to uppercase, lowercase, and alternate';

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $a = readline('Enter a string: ');
    echo "Output in uppercase: " , strtoupper($a). PHP_EOL;
    echo "Output in lowercase: " , strtolower($a);
}

/**
 * Define the command's schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
public function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
{
    // $schedule->command(static::class)->everyMinute();
}
}
```

so how can i add new line to show the input for example like this: "hElLo wOrLd"?

Comment: You can use [str_​split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to "_Convert a string to an array_", then iterate over the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Answer:**

```
$chars = str_split($a);
    foreach($chars as $char){
        if ($UpperLowerSwitch){
            
            echo strtolower($char);
            $UpperLowerSwitch = false;
        }else {
            echo strtoupper($char);
            $UpperLowerSwitch = true;
        }
    }
```

Output(if the user insert "hello world"):

```
hElLo wOrLd
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this **library** in laravel
here the example to understand this

it is easy way to use it

```
$lower=Illuminate\Support\Str::lower($value);
$upper=Illuminate\Support\Str::upper($value);
```

here [linke of docs and functions helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-lower)

Comment: i am able to get lowercase and upper case but i am looking for a third way to display it like this "hElLo wOrLd"

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shorter version, you can use the following code:

```php
$str = "stack overflow";
$arr = str_split($str);

$result = join(array_map(function($char, $i) {
    return $i % 2 ? strtoupper($char) : strtolower($char);
}, $arr, array_keys($arr)));

// Result: "sTaCk oVeRfLoW"
```

This uses the index of the character array (`i % 2` are the uneven indexes) to change the capitalization.

Wrap it into a nice function named `unreadableCapitalization($str)` and be done with it :)